# Cropped picture to the profile

Tags: javascript, image, crop

I would like to make a page, where there will be a "window", to which I will load some image. In this window it will be possible to move the image by the mouse. After clicking on some button the position of image will be saved (or image cropped? I don´t know how this would work) and the image will have the same position after reload of the page. Can anyone help me with this? I don´t even know where to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since there is no starting code to go off of, here is a general guide. You'll want to use a DIV with `overflow:hidden;`. Then, inside that DIV would be another DIV or IMG tag with your image. Once you have that, just Google "javascript draggable items" and code your inner DIV/IMG to be dragged. Once the image is dragged, you'll need to record the X, Y coordinates (in a database or other storage location). Once that X, Y coordinate is saved, you'll need to know that when the page next loads and set the images x, y (or margin) values accordingly. The specifics depend on your particular setup.

Comment: Thanks! That should be enough for start... :)

Comment: I just did a quick update to include positioning the picture on page load. Check it out.

Comment: Also, check out this fiddle I came across (http://jsfiddle.net/DqdRK/). Please note that this uses jQuery and jQueryUI for the dragging.

Comment: Very helpful! I think that´s all I need to know :) Thanks!